# AuthZForce for static page access

Tags: authzforce

I roughly know what a PEP (Policy Enforcemente Point) is

It intercepts the request for access, it constructs and sends the request to the PDP...etc

But I don't know how to use it in order to filter any access (from client) to a static page on a web server

Scenario:

```
Tomcat web server with a static web page only 
The static page should only be accessible from 9 am until 5 pm
```

I need a PEP and a PDP in order to accomplish my objective.

Is AuthZForce suitable for my needs?

I desperately need to find someone willing to help me to implement my project from scratch in step by step way
Is there anyone who I can get in touch with, personally?

Thanks a lot

Terence

Answer (score 0):

You may use [AuthzForce mailing list](https://github.com/authzforce/core#support).